# Nested For loop to get consecutive numbers in PHP

Tags: php, html, math

I have managed to use a nested for loop to make a number table like this.

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table border = 1>
<?php
   for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) 
   {
        print("<tr>");

        for($r = 1; $r <=5; $r++) 
        {
            print("<td>" . $i*$r . "</td>");
        }
        print("</tr>");
   }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

IT is a 5 by 5 table that looks like this.
[image]

The number in this table are not in order. I want it to look like this

[image]

I would like to know how you do this with PHP code please. thanks

Comment: What order would you like it to be..?

Comment: define the order..

Comment: what you want is not clear, share your expected output ?

Comment: You can do that with a single loop instead, and use `if ($i % 5 == 0) /* new row */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question right you want order numbers like `1,2,3,4...25`. This will create numbers in described order:

```
echo '<table border = 1>';
   $count = 1;
   for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) 
   {
        print("<tr>");
        for($r = 1; $r <=5; $r++) 
        {
            print("<td>" . $count . "</td>");
            $count++;
        }
        print("</tr>");
   }
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in one loop

```
<?php
 $number = 5;
 for($i = 0; $i < $number*$number; $i++) 
 {
    if($i % $number == 0){
      echo "\n";
    }
    echo ($i+1)."  ";
 }
?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/752068

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  
31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  
41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  
51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  
61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  
71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  
81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  
91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table>
<?php
$a = 0; //add this line
for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) 
{
    print("<tr>");

    for($r = 1; $r <=5; $r++) 
    {
        $a = $a+1; //add this line
        print("<td>" . $a . "</td>"); //edit this line
    }
    print("</tr>");
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will helps you

```
<table border = 1>
    <?php
    $k=0;
    for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) {
        print("<tr>");

        for($r = 1; $r <=5; $r++) {
            $k++;
            print("<td>" . $k . "</td>");
        }
        print("</tr>");
   }
   ?>
</table>
```